# using find function in javascript for array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have array

```
Game: [
  { game: 'SS', status: 2 },
  { game: 'CD', status: 2 },
  { game: 'AS', status: 2 },
  { game: 'SM', status: 2 },
  { game: 'GTA', status: 1 },
]
```

how can I find the GTA's status is equal to 1 using find method in js?

Comment: `const foundGame = Game.find(({ status }) => status === 1)` ?

Comment: [MDN's documentation of `find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) has several examples. What part of those are you not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method:

```
const games = Game.filter(gta => gta.status == 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Game.find(game => game.status===1)
```